# How to prevent user from logon of an account used for impersonation only?

Tags: c#, impersonation

Currently I have a windows service written in C# (running as LocalSystem) which creates a user account, needed for impersonation, by using the DirectoryEntry to add the user/password and associated UserFlags. Then it simply uses this account to perform some tasks (using impersonation) using the LogonUser() functionality - works perfectly.

However this account should ONLY be used for impersonation by my service, a user should NEVER be able to login (even if he has the credentials) locally or via the network.

To accomplish this I tried setting the Local Policies for “Deny logon locally” and “Deny access to this computer from the network” and added the user my service creates. Now however impersonation fails with the following:
    Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer (1385)

So, I guess this is NOT the right way to do it … but I need to secure lockdown the account so it can only be used by my service for impersonation purposes and to ensure that no one else can ever logon to the account (even if they have all the credentials).

Is there something in LSA I can use? Or using the DirectoryEntry code similar to when the account was created? Is there a way to allow for an account to exist but not allow users to interactively logon?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: You might try on serverfault.com  a lot of system admins hang out there.

Comment: Although your service was originally written in c#, your current question isn't a programming question. Recommend this be moved to serverfault.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't place any tags in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the service under the "Network Service" account and grant the server access to the applicable domain resources. Other than that, I am not certain there is a way to solve your problem with a user account.

Comment: Sadly that won't work - I need to mimic a real user ... I just need to ensure that the only way to use the user is via impersonation and deny it from ever being logged on by a physical user